# Determine the remainder we get if we divide $799^{801}$ by $264$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Determine the remainder we get if we divide  $799^{801}$ by $264$.
I need clear steps.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: I can get 799^800*&799≡1(264). Someone told me the answer is  799≡7(264). I don't understand where is from the 7.

Comment: $799 = 264\cdot 3 + 7$ therefore $799^{801} =(264\cdot 3 + 7)^{801}$. The only term in that huge expansion that isnt already divisible by 264 is $7^{801}$

Comment: You do need to give a brief description of what class you are in and what you have studied so for. If you know the Eulers Theorem it's straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

$799\equiv7\pmod{264},799^n\equiv7^n$ for integer $n\ge0$

Using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), $\lambda(264)=$lcm$(\lambda(3),\lambda(8),\lambda(11))=10$

As $(7,264)=1$

$$\implies7^{801}\equiv7^{801\pmod{10}}\equiv7^1\pmod{264}$$

Comment: Hello, where is from the 7?

Comment: @Y.xin, $$799\%264=?$$

Comment: @Y.xin, Are you aware of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: Getting to $7$ is easy: You take $799$ and subtract $264$ you will have $535$ then subtract $264$ again you will have $271$ one again will get you $7$. In other words **799** =3 x  **264**  +  **7**.

Comment: Thanks, I will see.