# solving congruence $a^{6p−6} \equiv 1 \pmod{9p}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a positive prime number different from $3$ and $a$ be an integer not divisible neither by $3$ nor by $p$. Show that in this case $a^{6p−6} \equiv 1 \pmod{9p}$

Comment: Not a bad time to share your effort after https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038266/determine-the-remainder-we-get-if-we-divide-799801-by-264

Comment: I have no idea about solving an equation. I need an example. If I know the first solution, I can do it in a similar way.

Comment: Apply [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), since $\varphi(9p)=\varphi(9)\cdot \varphi(p)$

Comment: I don't know what's the next steps. I get φ(9p)= 6⋅φ(p).